# Probability distribution of $\omega'(n)$.

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

$\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\omega'(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity. For example if $p,q$ are prime numbers then $\omega(p^2q)=2$ and $\omega'(p^2q)=3$.

What is the distribution of $\omega'(n)$ for $n$ between $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$ where $m$ is a sufficiently large integer?

Do we have with probability at least $\frac12$ at least $\log\log n$ indistinct factors?

Comment: [do you know $\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) ? note that $\ln \zeta(s) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$. assume instead that $\ln \zeta(s) = \sum_{p^k} (p^k)^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\omega(n) = 1} n^{-s}$ what can you say of $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = e^{\ln \zeta(s)} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\ln \zeta(s))^m}{m!}$ ? do you think it is related to $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = 1+\sum_{a=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\omega(n) = a} n^{-s}$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625455/probability-that-a-number-has-m-indistinct-factors

Comment: @JohnM so do we have with probability at least $\frac12$ at least $\log\log n$ factors?

Comment: the square-free number haves density $\frac{6}{\pi^2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} > 1/2$. and what is the minimal number of factors of a square-free number $n$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Why is square-free number density $\frac6\pi^2$?

Comment: because of the theory of $\zeta(s)$, its dominating pole at $s=1$, and that $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(n)| n^{-s}$ where $|\mu(n)|$ indicates the square free  numbers. that's why I asked if you knew $\zeta(s)$

Comment: @user1952009 actually no.

Comment: then you can see that for understanding $\omega(n)$, and many things about the prime numbers, it is very useful

Comment: @user1952009 may be you can provide a detailed reasoning from $zeta$ function view.

Comment: yes, forget what I said about the number of prime factors of square free numbers, it's not helpful

Comment: @user1952009 why do you say that?

Comment: Yes by the famous Erdos-Kac theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) the number of prime factors of $n$ is normally distributed with mean $\log \log n$ and variance $\log \log n$.

Comment: @JohnM indistinct factors.

Comment: Same for both.  See first link to other MSE question.